# How to implement Vue integration in existing website

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to integrate VueJs into one of my customer websites and I have the following problem:

I want to convert only part of the components of the website and I don’t seem to find the way to render two components in two different places on the page.

I am using the simple project of vue-cli, there main.js renders only one parent component, so I can’t for example render a subcomponent in the header and another in the footer because they have to be in the same parent container.

This is my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import {store} from './store/index'
import VueLazyload from 'vue-lazyload'

Vue.use(VueLazyload);

import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

I hope I was clear and will really appreciate your help.

Thank you

Comment: Could you present a simplified HTML file that indicates where you would want Vue to control and where you would not? Do you want two Vue instances that share data?